# Screwed up DNS settings in 13.10

Tags: networking, dns, settings

When I run

```
nslookup internal.foo.com
```

I get

```
Server:         127.0.1.1
Address:        127.0.1.1#53

** server can't find internal.foo.com: NXDOMAIN
```

For some reason, I am not getting the 172.17.51.3 internal DNS server I added.
How do I fix this (via command-line if possible)?

/etc/resolv.conf

```
nameserver 127.0.1.1
search foo.com
```

/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Ethernet\ connection\ 1

```
[802-3-ethernet]
duplex=full

[connection]
id=Ethernet connection 1
uuid=4ccfdffe-b3e5-4fb2-906f-28a3e1c7a71b
type=802-3-ethernet
timestamp=1387729723

[ipv6]
method=auto

[ipv4]
method=manual
dns=172.17.51.3;8.8.8.8;
dns-search=foo.com;
address1=172.17.51.9/24,172.17.51.1
```

**SOLUTION**

I don't know why NetworkManager seems to be misbehaving, but following the instructions
from [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/368435/38516) seems to work.

Essentially, you appear to have to do something like this:

```
echo "nameserver 172.17.51.3
nameserver 8.8.8.8
search foo.com" | sudo resolvconf -a eth0.inet
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your nameserver setting isn't correct here. try removing that line and making it `8.8.8.8` (Google DNS which you have set in the `NetworkManager`). If you look in the query it is using the `127.0.1.1` (Which is a localhost typo of `127.0.0.1`)

Comment: actually, I need to look at my internal DNS server 172.17.51.3 first for the ip mapping to internal.foo.com (foo.com is my internal domain) - what is the correct format in that file?