# Unable to go online but still able to ping, either with wlan0 or eth0

Tags: 14.10, internet, connection, ping

I have a Dell Inspiron 17 r 5737 with Ubuntu 14.10.
Ar the moment, my laptop is able to connect both to eth0 and wlan0 connections, but I cannot go online with any browser, with apt-get or any other software.
But the strangest thing is that I AM ABLE to ping... What's happening?
:(

UPDATE:

When I try to visit a website with firefox or chrome, I don't get any message and the browser keeps 'loading' for a very long time (more than 5 min).

Then, on chromium I get `'This page is not available'` while firefox keeps trying forever...
I can ping 8.8.8.8 but not google.com
So I guess I have some DNS problem. How can I fix this?

Going to connection information my primary DNS is the address of my router (192.168.1.1). This issue affects only my laptop and not other devices connected to my network.

wget gets stuck at `'Resolving google.com (google.com)...'`

Comment: What happens when you try to browse something on the internet using a browser? Can you name a specific address are you able to ping but not browse to?

Comment: @Qerubin You don't need to add "SOLVED" in your title of question :)

Comment: @KasiyA Understood, Sir! ^_^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It might be DNS problem, try to ping by IP and by some name, eg.:

   ```
   ping 8.8.8.8
   ping example.com
   ```

If the second command gives you name-resolve errors, head for fixing your DNS. First, check if `/etc/resolv.conf` contains proper setup for your network, you need at last a line like this:

```
    nameserver [your_dns_server]
```

2. It might be HTTP restriction on your network, try some command-line approach, to see actual error, and a result of this request, maybe like this:

   ```
   cd ~/Desktop
   wget http://google.com
   ```

Is `Desktop/index.html` downloaded here? Is it HTML document starting with `<!doctype html>...`? Can you open it with browser? Does it contains some error text?

Comment: I updated the main question. Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: Thank you so much! It WAS a DNS error! Fixed it by following this :) http://askubuntu.com/questions/368435/how-do-i-fix-dns-resolving-which-doesnt-work-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-13-10-s