# Ubuntu 16.04 - offline after update

Tags: internet, offline

After taking some updates requiring reboot on my lubuntu 16.04 I am now unable to connect to the internet (neither Ethernet nor WiFi).

Could someone guide me through please?
Thank you very much in advance!
Markus

Comment: Via what means wifi and/or ethernet?

Comment: run this `sudo apt-cache pkgnames apt-offline` and post the result(s)...

Comment: apt-offline; apt-offline-gui

Comment: And it opens a notice from Dropbox saying that the computer is offline, and that I should check the network settings.

Comment: try this first `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56502/discussion-between-markus-and-george).

Comment: It stops the 5 bars of connection strength and puts them back. It says that it is connected, burping gets stuck.

Comment: Glad you got it fixed...please post an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution here:
[How do I fix DNS resolving which doesn't work after upgrading to Ubuntu 13.10 (Saucy)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/368435/how-do-i-fix-dns-resolving-which-doesnt-work-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-13-10-s)

1. LAN was back after this:
   `sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf`
2. In order to get the WiFi back I needed to:
   `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager`

Thanks for help.