# DNS for local domain failing after update

Tags: dns

I ran an update yesterday and ever since local DNS has not worked. External works fine. In fact, I have several overrides in my local DNS server to point external sites to internal IPs and those are now responding with the original external IPs. I only have 192.168.0.1 (my DNS server) specified in /etc/network/interface with

```
dns-nameservers 192.168.0.1
```

I'm guessing something changed in the new updates I installed and /etc/network/interface is no longer the place to specify DNS server... but I can't find anything.

Edit:
I should add that I can ping FQDN but not the short names. Which I could prior to the 5/30 update. After a couple days of searching around I haven't found anything... and short names still don't work.

Comment: Can you look in the apt logfile and edit your question to show what got upgraded?

Comment: Same here, I fixed it by bypassing dnsmasq - https://askubuntu.com/a/432374/596582

Comment: @OrganicMarble
Here is the log:
https://pastebin.com/gpTL0hKp

Comment: @JIV, I saw that mentioned in a few posts but every solution mentioned editing /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf and I didn't have NetworkManager installed... so that couldn't be the solution for me. I installed it and played around a bit but no love.

Comment: In the list of updates I do see an update to dnsmasq-base. I'm not sure how to bypass that though since I didn't have a /etc/NetworkManager dir prior to installing NetworkManager. Even though I removed it the dir and .conf are still there. After editing it and rebooting there is still no change in behavior. I don't think the NetworkManager.conf is related to my issue.