# No internet access, lubuntu 17.04, eeepc 1001pxd

Tags: lubuntu, internet, connection, eeepc

I just installed lubuntu 17.04 without problems. The pc also connects to my wifi, but I can not go to any websites in firefox (or search for updates etc.).

I tried connecting it to the router with an ethernet cable, which gave the same result.

I can ping the DNS ip adress (127.0.0.53) without problems.

I have tried removing the battery and waiting a bit again as recommended on other pages.

What should I try next? I am new to ubuntu.

Best,

Comment: I have the same Problem on a fresh install on an acer Extensa 5220

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this temporarily by adding some needed IPs to your `/etc/hosts` file, for example:

```
sudo su
echo "security.ubuntu.com 91.189.91.23">>/etc/hosts
echo "us.archive.ubuntu.com 91.189.91.23">>/etc/hosts
echo "de.archive.ubuntu.com 141.76.1.200">>/etc/hosts
echo "google.com 172.217.22.206">>/etc/hosts
echo "google.de 172.217.22.195">>/etc/hosts
```

Then you can use your browser and apt without a working DNS to fix the issue:

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

(use export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive for this upgrade, otherwise you can run into problems on the console)

After a reboot DNS will start working correctly.

---

Additional info: At first I did this:

```
sudo systemctl disable systemd-resolved.service
```

as suggested [here](https://github.com/cpriego/valet-linux/issues/7#issuecomment-282188307) and rebooted, but that didn't help, but it could be needed for my solution to work.