# Fresh 16.04 install, network not working

Tags: 16.04, networking

New install on a new Dell machine.  It came with windows 10, which I booted briefly, and did connect to the internet, so I know the card and connection are working.

Install went fine, it configured the network interface, and said it was going out to get the time.  Only thing during the install was that when it came for the choice of packages to be installed, I couldn't find the proper keystroke to set the packages I wanted.  No big deal, I would just install them once the machine was up.

I'm not at the machine now, wanted to get this thread started in case anyone else has something similar and could hand off their experience.  I'll post more later, but simply, an "ifconfig" shows the device (enp3s0 is it?) to be up and running and no issues.  Everything I did that I could find online had no effect.

Also it doesn't seem that Network Manager is on the machine, is that a package that has to be installed?

I will post specific info later today, but if anyone has a list of things I can try, I would appreciate it.

Thanks,

Mickey

Comment: Maybe DNS issue. You can see [this] (https://askubuntu.com/questions/368435/how-do-i-fix-dns-resolving-which-doesnt-work-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-13-10-s/368935#368935)

Comment: Turns out it was the router.  All other connections were working, rebooting the router and the network was up on this machine.  Thanks!

Comment: Well done! I've got a D-Link modem, sometimes I have to do it, too. Post this as an answer, so your issue may be "solved"

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in a comment, it was the router.  A reboot took care of it.  I should have thought of that but didn't suspect it, as all the other devices connected were working fine.

In some ways, the computer world hasn't changed in 40 years.  When in doubt, reboot!