# How do I configure DNS resolution if resolvconf doesn't work?

Tags: networking, server, dns, ifconfig

My `/etc/resolv.conf` will not be written so DNS resolution is not working.

I'm running Ubuntu Server 16.04.1 LTS in a virtual machine on our office server.

This is my `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto ens3
iface ens3 inet static
        address 192.168.222.104
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.222.1
        gateway 192.168.222.1
        dns-nameservers 192.168.222.1 8.8.8.8
        dns-search internal.domain
        post-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.up.rules
```

(`/etc/network/interfaces.d` is empty)

I've already tried running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf` and `sudo ln -sf /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf` as mentioned in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/368935/423684). But my `/etc/resolv.conf` still remains empty:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
```

**What else can I try to get DNS resolution back on this server?**

**NOTE:**
The same setup works on the other 5 servers which run Ubuntu in other VMs on the same hardware.

They all show a `/etc/resolv.conf` like

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 192.168.222.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
search internal.domain
```

and for those DNS resolution works perfect.

**Is there any configuration I'm missing?**

Just in case I also added my `/etc/iptables.up.rules` (which is also more or less the same on all 6 Servers and) which I've set up taking some hints from [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-implement-a-basic-firewall-template-with-iptables-on-ubuntu-14-04):

```
*filter
# Allow all outgoing, but drop incoming and forwarding packets by default
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]

# Custom per-protocol chains
:UDP - [0:0]
:TCP - [0:0]
:ICMP - [0:0]

# Acceptable UDP traffic

# Acceptable TCP traffic
-A TCP -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A TCP -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A TCP -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A TCP -p tcp --dport 10000 -j ACCEPT

# Acceptable ICMP traffic
-A ICMP -p icmp -j ACCEPT

# Boilerplate acceptance policy
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

# Drop invalid packets
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP

# Pass traffic to protocol-specific chains
## Only allow new connections (established and related should already be handled)
## For TCP, additionally only allow new SYN packets since that is the only valid
## method for establishing a new TCP connection
-A INPUT -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j UDP
-A INPUT -p tcp --syn -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j TCP
-A INPUT -p icmp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ICMP

# Reject anything that's fallen through to this point
## Try to be protocol-specific w/ rejection message
-A INPUT -p udp -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A INPUT -p tcp -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-proto-unreachable

# Commit the changes
COMMIT

*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
COMMIT

*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
COMMIT

*security
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
COMMIT

*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
COMMIT
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to update the DNS servers in

```
/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base
```

then run

```
sudo resolvconf -u
```

to regenerate the `resolv.conf` file.

Comment: the file `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base` is empty .. how should it look like? And will this permanently fix the problem? Since it is an office server I can't reconfigure it all the time e.g. after reboots, updates etc.

Comment: @derHugo the file is empty by default. You add lines that should appear in `/etc/resolv.conf` to it (for example, `nameserver 192.168.222.1`, or `search internal.domain`). The file is read by `resolvconf` whenever it updates, so it should persist across reboots.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, it is better not to edit resolv.conf, and that is because network manager would update everything you have written by hand, with each restart of the network or reboot. So I would use the nmcli command:

```
nmcli con mod ens3 +ipv4.dns 192.168.222.1 8.8.8.8
nmcli con up ens3
```

Network manager is installed by default in most ubuntu based distros, so I assume that would also be the case. Hope this helps!

Comment: Nice intempt but `nmcli` and `network-manager` are not installed since it is Ubuntu-Server without GUI.