# My internet suddenly stopped working

Tags: networking, internet

I have an Acer dual-boot laptop and internet was working perfectly fine, till today. I was busy programming and wanted to look something up, but the sites wouldn't load. It says I'm connected, but it still wouldn't work. The same internet is working on all other devices. I've tried everything to get it working again. I spent hours looking for answers on forums. I would really appreciate some help. Thanks in advance!

Some information that might help you understand my problem:

`ping -c 4 8.8.8.8` would return `4 packets transmitted, 4 receiver, 0% packet loss, time 3005ms`

`nslookup google.com` would return `;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached`

Security: WPA/WPA2

Driver: iwlwifi

Interface: 802.11 WiFi (wlp3s0)

IPv4 Method is set to Automatic (DHCP)

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3

0:300.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:24fb] (rev 
10)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2110]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

Comment: DNS problem. Try changing the DNS server to Google's.

Comment: @MichaelBay is right - it sounds like a DNS problem. You can check by changing the DNS server in NSLookup (`nslookup` <enter>, `server 8.8.8.8` <enter>, `www.yahoo.com` <enter>).

Comment: @Vanessa Deagan
`> server 8.8.8.8` returned `Default server 8.8.8.8 Address: 8.8.8.8#53` and `www.yahoo.com` returned me a bunch of text. I added 8.8.8.8 to my DNS servers but it still isn't working

Comment: @Boomer > when you say "bunch of text", can you see if it resolved "www.yahoo.com" to an IP address? The last line should be something like: `Address: 46.228.47.115` (although the IP address may differ).

Comment: Sorry for being so unspecific. www.yahoo.com returns 

`Server: 8.8.8.8`
`Address: 8.8.8.8#53`
`Non-authoritative answer: www.yahoo.com canonical name = atsv2-fp.wg1.b.yahoo.com`
`Name: atsv2-fp.wg1.b.yahoo.com`
`Address 46.228.47.115`

Comment: @Vanessa Deagan Forgot to tag you

Comment: Then @MichaelBay is correct - it's a DNS issue. You need to go in to your Network Manager and [change your DNS settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/368435/how-do-i-fix-dns-resolving-which-doesnt-work-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-13-10-s).

Comment: @MichaelBay I went over and changed my IPv4 settings to 'automatic (DHCP) addresses only' and I added '8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4' to the 'DNS servers:' section. However it's still not working :(

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of  `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command, just in case it's something related to the specific device and some update. That said I'm more inclined to an hardware failure at this point.

Comment: I eddited my comment @MichaelBay

Comment: Seems fine, i.e., as it should be. Try rebooting the router. Other than that thereś probably nothing to do besides replacing the card.

Comment: @MichaelBay Alright! Thank you for helping me nontheless! I'll inform you when its working again.