# DHCP client no longer assigning DNS

Tags: networking, dns, dhcp

Today for some reason my Ethernet adaptor stopped assigning DNS server info via DHCP request. Wifi works without problems. 
I was getting this error in Chrome DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_CONFIG. I looked it up and the suggestion was to run `dpkg-reconfigure resolve.conf` and then reboot. So that's what I did. It worked, but when I shutdown and restart the problem returns. The interface won't resolve DNS requests but I can load web pages in the browser if I enter their IP address.

When I do '`nmcli device show enp3s0`' there is no DNS entry for the wired ethernet adaptor. So it seems that DHCP client is no longer setting DNS information. If I assign the DNS server in network manager then I am able to use the interface as expected. I'm not a long time Ubuntu user so I'm looking for hints on how to troubleshoot this.

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Dell Latitude 3470

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me after updating to 17.10. I've found the solution on [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/368435/how-do-i-fix-dns-resolving-which-doesnt-work-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-13-10-s) thread

I hope you can fix your problem.