# Ubuntu 14.04 failing apt update - connection failed security/archive.ubuntu.com

Tags: 14.04, apt

I am trying to run `apt update` on Ubuntu 14.04 installed from `trusty-server-cloudimg-amd64.ova`.

I can see the `apt-get` traffic is being allowed in the firewall.

I ran `sudo apt update` and below is what I get:

```
Err http://minmeld-updates.pan.io trusty-minemeld InRelease

Err http://minmeld-updates.pan.io trusty-minemeld Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'minmeld-updates.pan.io'
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Ign http://minemeld-updates.panw.io trusty-minemeld InRelease
```

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 0):

Start by pinging the server:

```
ping -c 4 archive.ubuntu.com
```

if you can reach it, which looks like this:

```
$ ping -c 4 archive.ubuntu.com
PING archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.88.161) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from keeton.canonical.com (91.189.88.161): icmp_seq=1 ttl=53 time=47.4 ms
64 bytes from keeton.canonical.com (91.189.88.161): icmp_seq=2 ttl=53 time=47.9 ms
64 bytes from keeton.canonical.com (91.189.88.161): icmp_seq=3 ttl=53 time=48.5 ms
64 bytes from keeton.canonical.com (91.189.88.161): icmp_seq=4 ttl=53 time=46.4 ms

--- archive.ubuntu.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3005ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 46.490/4

7.605/48.529/0.743 ms
```

you can try disabling IPv6 addressing in GUI:

- In the top right find the networking indicator icon
- Select edit connections
- Edit you current connection (double-click)
- Under IPv6 settings/method, choose Ignore
- Save and exit
- Try it!
- Update us

Or CLI:

```
$ sudo sh -c 'echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/eth0/disable_ipv6'
```

Of course, you should replace 'eth0' with any other interface if it's not the one you're using, or 'all' to do it on all interfaces. This will only work until you reboot though.

Comment: ubuntu@minemeld:~$ ping -c 4 archive.ubuntu.com
PING archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.88.152) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from steelix.canonical.com (91.189.88.152): icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=100 ms

Comment: ubuntu@minemeld:~$ ping -c 4 archive.ubuntu.com
PING archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.88.152) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from steelix.canonical.com (91.189.88.152): icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=100 ms

Comment: This is a server with no gui.  Not sure how to disable ipv6 on it.

Comment: edited for CLI method

Comment: Still failing:Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted amd64 Packages
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe amd64 Packages
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-en_US
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]

Comment: can you confirm you only have an ipv4 address in ifconfig?

Comment: ubuntu@minemeld:~$ sudo ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:b2:1a:94
          inet addr:172.28.105.224  Bcast:172.28.105.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5951 errors:0 dropped:9 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2652 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:526616 (526.6 KB)  TX bytes:358118 (358.1 KB)

Comment: I'm afraid this is as much help as i can give you. You did 'apt-get update' right?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  It is still failing but I appreciate your time!

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in happening after the [ubuntu 12.04,
is a problem between the dnsmasq and resolvconf](https://askubuntu.com/questions/368435/how-do-i-fix-dns-resolving-which-doesnt-work-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-13-10-s).

Be the correct way to fix it is to restart the network-manager service, to it get the right dns:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Or

install resolvconf

```
sudo apt install resolvconf
```