# How to repair DNS resolution in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: dnsmasq

Recently, name resolution failed on Ubuntu 16.04, and I worked around the problem by adding "nameserver 127.0.0.1" to /etc/resolv.conf (which fixed the problem)

I know I should not be manually editing /etc/resolv.conf in 16.04

What package(s) can I reinstall to get DNS resolution back to the pristine state for 16.04?

Comment: You can try to run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf` to repair symlink between `/etc/resolv.conf` and `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf` as recommended in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/368935/66509).

Comment: If you need fixed DNS entries, you should be editing the files located in `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d`.  I did my permanent DNS server entries in the `original` file located in that folder.  Then when completed you should run `sudo resolvconf -u` to update the `/etc/resolv.conf` file.