# Ubuntu 16.04 DNS resolving is broken

Tags: networking, 16.04, internet, dns

I have a post going on Ubuntu Forums about this issue but the it has stalled and the issue isn't resolved so I'm trying to tap in to the ask community for help.

I had a perfectly working 16.04 dual boot install. Needing to use some Windows software for work I replaced a long unused W7 install on a separate partition with W10. Both are now up and running. Except...

DNS is now broken.

I ran the wireless-info script and here is the output:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 28 Mar 2020 13:57 CDT -0500

Booted last: 28 Mar 2020 00:00 CDT -0500

Script from: 22 Oct 2018 03:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.4.0-176-generic #206-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 28 05:02:04 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6230 [Rainbow Peak] [8086:0091] (rev 34)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6230 AGN [8086:5201]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi

03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [144d:c0b3]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 004: ID 8086:0189 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 2232:1018 Silicon Motion 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: samsung-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: samsung-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### secure boot #######################

'mokutil' is not installed (package "mokutil").

##### lsmod #############################

iwldvm                233472  0
mac80211              737280  1 iwldvm
iwlwifi               200704  1 iwldvm
cfg80211              565248  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwldvm
wmi                    20480  0

##### interfaces ########################

[/etc/network/interfaces]
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp3s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'enp3s0' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
3: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'wlp2s0' [IF2]> brd <MAC address>
    inet 192.168.1.235/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic wlp2s0
       valid_lft 85270sec preferred_lft 85270sec
    inet6 fe80::2e0c:1e32:b88a:82e3/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp3s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:"wewantutopia1"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.24 GHz  Access Point: <MAC 'wewantutopia1' [AC1]>   
          Bit Rate=216 Mb/s   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=66/70  Signal level=-44 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:218   Missed beacon:0

##### route #############################

default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp2s0  proto static  metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp2s0  scope link  metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp2s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.235  metric 600 

##### resolv.conf #######################

[644 root '/etc/resolv.conf']

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root      1113     1  0 13:02 ?        00:00:01 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp2s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Intel Corporation
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        Centrino Advanced-N 6230 [Rainbow Peak] (Centrino Advanced-N 6230 AGN)
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         iwlwifi
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 4.4.0-176-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               18.168.6.1
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'wlp2s0' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            0
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:02:00.0/net/wlp2s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       wlp2s0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     wewantutopia1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       8a1c8ae7-8747-4b1f-b680-46adf64c8d5d
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     135 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   yes
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{2,11,15,0}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   56e522fc-943c-410a-9c77-2dad2a474725 | Chromecast7090
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[2]:   483741ba-f753-4ae2-96ac-e1b61001e052 | wewantutopia
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[3]:   ce43afef-d62c-4b30-8a92-4bf6e0762a2d | wewantutopia2
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[4]:   8a1c8ae7-8747-4b1f-b680-46adf64c8d5d | wewantutopia1
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.235/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.1.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        domain_name_servers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        ip_address = 192.168.1.235
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        broadcast_address = 192.168.1.255
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       dhcp_rebinding_time = 75600
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       routers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       wpad = a
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       dhcp_renewal_time = 43200
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       expiry = 1585507129
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       host_name = dk
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       network_number = 192.168.1.0
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[29]:                       next_server = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[30]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[31]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 86400
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::2e0c:1e32:b88a:82e3/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         <MAC address>
GENERAL.TYPE:                           bt
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceBt
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         bluez
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC address>
GENERAL.MTU:                            0
GENERAL.STATE:                          30 (disconnected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F8_95_C7_17_A5_D2
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
BLUETOOTH.CAPABILITIES:                 NAP
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{24}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   79b25038-b298-4091-b989-734fac4921a3 | Dave's LG G4  Network

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp3s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp3s0' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         40 (Carrier/link changed)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:03:00.0/net/enp3s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     1000 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: 

SSID            BSSID              MODE   CHAN  FREQ      RATE       SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  ACTIVE  * 
wewantutopia    <MAC 'wewantutopia' [AC2]>  Infra  9     2452 MHz  54 Mbit/s  97      ▂▄▆█  WPA2      no        
wewantutopia2   <MAC 'wewantutopia2' [AC5]>  Infra  161   5805 MHz  54 Mbit/s  77      ▂▄▆_  WPA2      no        
wewantutopia1   <MAC 'wewantutopia1' [AC1]>  Infra  48    5240 MHz  54 Mbit/s  76      ▂▄▆_  WPA2      yes     * 
Chromecast7090  <MAC '' [AC4]>  Infra  9     2452 MHz  54 Mbit/s  74      ▂▄▆_  --        no        
ATT8N58wnt      <MAC 'ATT8N58wnt' [AC3]>  Infra  11    2462 MHz  54 Mbit/s  37      ▂▄__  WPA2      no        

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq
[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########




[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/wewantutopia1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=wewantutopia1 | type=wifi | permissions=user:david:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlp2s0' [IF2]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=wewantutopia1
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/wewantutopia2]] (600 root)
[connection] id=wewantutopia2 | type=wifi | permissions=user:david:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlp2s0' [IF2]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=wewantutopia2
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/wewantutopia]] (600 root)
[connection] id=wewantutopia | type=wifi | permissions=user:david:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlp2s0' [IF2]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=wewantutopia
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### Netplan config ####################

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: America/Chicago (based on set time zone)

country US: DFS-FCC
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 30), (N/A)
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 23), (N/A)
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 23), (0 ms), DFS
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 23), (0 ms), DFS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 30), (N/A)
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 40), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

enp3s0    no frequency information.

wlp2s0    32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
          Channel 128 : 5.64 GHz
          Channel 132 : 5.66 GHz
          Channel 136 : 5.68 GHz
          Channel 140 : 5.7 GHz
          Channel 149 : 5.745 GHz
          Channel 153 : 5.765 GHz
          Current Frequency:5.24 GHz (Channel 48)

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp3s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

Channel occupancy:

      2   APs on   Frequency:2.452 GHz (Channel 9)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
      1   APs on   Frequency:5.24 GHz (Channel 48)
      1   APs on   Frequency:5.805 GHz

wlp2s0    Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC 'wewantutopia1' [AC1]>
                    Channel:48
                    Frequency:5.24 GHz (Channel 48)
                    Quality=66/70  Signal level=-44 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"wewantutopia1"
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                              36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000007f6cf5a37d
                    Extra: Last beacon: 300ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 02 - Address: <MAC 'wewantutopia' [AC2]>
                    Channel:9
                    Frequency:2.452 GHz (Channel 9)
                    Quality=70/70  Signal level=-36 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"wewantutopia"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000007f6cc7ed08
                    Extra: Last beacon: 3156ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK

          Cell 05 - Address: <MAC 'wewantutopia2' [AC5]>
                    Channel:161
                    Frequency:5.805 GHz
                    Quality=56/70  Signal level=-54 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"wewantutopia2"
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                              36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000007f6cbd63fb
                    Extra: Last beacon: 136ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK

##### module infos ######################

[iwldvm]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-176-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/dvm/iwldvm.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi Link AGN driver for Linux
srcversion:     58FF645F7DE3DD061B613D8
depends:        mac80211,iwlwifi,cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-176-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           force_cam:force continuously aware mode (no power saving at all) (bool)

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-176-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     CD58AC927E26FDA6A73F559
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-176-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[iwlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-176-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265D-13.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-13.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-13.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-13.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000-13.ucode
srcversion:     CB5AC244E1344F14798FC7E
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-176-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size_8K:enable 8K amsdu size (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB (default: 0 dB) (int)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           d0i3_disable:disable d0i3 functionality (default: Y) (bool)
parm:           lar_disable:disable LAR functionality (default: N) (bool)
parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality (default: Y) (bool)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm:           fw_monitor:firmware monitor - to debug FW (default: false - needs lots of memory) (bool)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-176-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     649B1B8B37AC928F18974F4
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-176-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[iwldvm]
force_cam: Y

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[iwlwifi]
11n_disable: 0
amsdu_size_8K: 0
antenna_coupling: 0
bt_coex_active: Y
d0i3_disable: Y
fw_monitor: N
fw_restart: Y
lar_disable: N
led_mode: 0
nvm_file: (null)
power_level: 0
power_save: N
swcrypto: 0
uapsd_disable: Y

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

coretemp

coretemp

coretemp

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel_powerclamp.conf]
install intel_powerclamp /bin/true

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[  114.131817] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Not sending command - RF KILL
[  114.131821] wlp2s0: failed to remove key (2, <MAC address>) from hardware (-5)
[  114.132105] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Not sending command - RF KILL (repeated 2 times)
[  135.744805] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: link up
[  135.744817] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp3s0: link becomes ready
[  192.807649] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: link down
[ 2183.322203] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to enable radio.
[ 2183.322493] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled (repeated 2 times)
[ 2183.329227] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x2-0x0
[ 2183.604254] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled (repeated 2 times)
[ 2183.610955] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x2-0x0
[ 2183.695256] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready (repeated 2 times)
[ 2189.909693] wlp2s0: authenticate with <MAC 'wewantutopia1' [AC1]>
[ 2189.911907] wlp2s0: send auth to <MAC 'wewantutopia1' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[ 2189.930345] wlp2s0: authenticated
[ 2189.931877] wlp2s0: associate with <MAC 'wewantutopia1' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[ 2189.932703] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'wewantutopia1' [AC1]> (capab=0x1011 status=0 aid=1)
[ 2189.935028] wlp2s0: associated
[ 2189.935075] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp2s0: link becomes ready
[ 2190.032149] wlp2s0: Limiting TX power to 30 (30 - 0) dBm as advertised by <MAC 'wewantutopia1' [AC1]>

########## wireless info END ############
```

Here is the output of:

```
ls -la /etc/resolv.conf
ping 9.9.9.9 -c 4
nslookup google.de 9.9.9.9
nslookup google.de
dpkg -l |grep dnsmasq
dpkg -l |grep resolvconf
cat /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
```

```
david@dk:~$ ls -la /etc/resolv.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 715 Mar 27 15:32 /etc/resolv.conf


david@dk:~$ ping 9.9.9.9 -c 4
PING 9.9.9.9 (9.9.9.9) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 9.9.9.9: icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=15.0 ms
64 bytes from 9.9.9.9: icmp_seq=2 ttl=57 time=15.5 ms
64 bytes from 9.9.9.9: icmp_seq=3 ttl=57 time=22.4 ms
64 bytes from 9.9.9.9: icmp_seq=4 ttl=57 time=12.8 ms

--- 9.9.9.9 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 12.813/16.477/22.487/3.619 ms

david@dk:~$ nslookup google.de 9.9.9.9
Server:     9.9.9.9
Address:    9.9.9.9#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.de
Address: 172.217.4.227

david@dk:~$ nslookup google.de
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

david@dk:~$ dpkg -l |grep dnsmasq
ii  dnsmasq-base                                  2.75-1ubuntu0.16.04.5                           amd64        Small caching DNS proxy and DHCP/TFTP server

david@dk:~$ dpkg -l |grep resolvconf
ii  resolvconf                                    1.78ubuntu7                                     all          name server information handler

david@dk:~$  cat /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf: nameserver 127.0.1.1
```

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally figured it out after pouring through countless threads between here and Ubuntu Forums. I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1062394/how-to-repair-dns-resolution-in-ubuntu-16-04) thread and ran:

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf`

to repair symlink between /etc/resolv.conf and /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf

I have functioning web connection again!!!!!!!!!!!