# Can't connect to internet Lubuntu 18.04

Tags: server, 18.04, lubuntu

I can't connect to the internet with my Lubuntu 18.04. It shows the wifi adapter with the signal bars and says that it's connected, but Firefox says: can't connect to server and Sudo apt-get update says Failed to Fetch.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal commands: `ping -c3 8.8.8.8` and also: `ping -c3 www.google.com` and also: `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf`  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Take the following steps:

- open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- In the terminal type:

  ```
  ping www.google.com
  ```
- You will probably get time out as reply or not a reply at all
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to stop the ping command.
- In the terminal now type:

  ```
  ping 1.1.1.1
  ```

  This will try to ping Cloudflare's DNS. If you get replies then the problem lies [within your DNS server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/368435/how-do-i-fix-dns-resolving-which-doesnt-work-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-13-10-s).

If you don't get a reply then you are not connected to the Internet through your router. (which is en issue outside of Ubuntu and off-topic here)