# Troubleshooting DNS: Only Ubuntu Wifi is symptomatic

Tags: dns

16.04 wifi was operating normally until the home router was overhauled today.  Wifi service was restored and the OSX / IOS wifi devices are running well.   The 16.04 wifi is able to ping the gateway:

```
 $ ping -c 3 192.168.8.1
```

however replacing the gateway ip with `yahoo.com` returns:

```
 $ ping -c 3 192.168.8.1
 ping: unknown host yahoo.com
```

yahoo.com resolved to 72.30.35.9 and pinging 72.30.35.9 was successful: this leads me to believe there is a DNS failure. Router provides DHCP service

Interesting observations:

- The OSX box does not suffer said DNS failures.
- 16.04 wifi works perfectly with cellular wifi hotspot

## Question

What **tests can be performed** to confirm the problem and determine corrective action?

## UPDATES

**DNS-based Filtering was turned off in the router and the problem is now resolved.**

Per Stephen Boston:

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
```

Per Stephen Boston:

```
ls -l /etc/resolv.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Nov 13  2018 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
```

Flushing DNS Cache did not resolve issue:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
[sudo] password for user: 
[ ok ] Restarting networking (via systemctl): networking.service.
```

Comment: Is the router also your DHCP server? Or is your Ubuntu system on a static (LAN) IP address?

Comment: Oh, and on 16.04, take a look at some of these almost similar problems: https://askubuntu.com/questions/368435 . I recall needing to fix DNS in 16.04.

Comment: @user535733 Which of the answers to your link do you suggest?

Comment: Check your /var/log/syslog for name-resolution errors. My own problem (long ago) generated huge logfiles, which made it easy to spot and diagnose.

Comment: @user535733   Please see OP: "Updates".  16.04 wifi DNS seems to work with smartphone hotspot: maybe this is a clue?

Comment: Since your Ubuntu system networking works properly with the phone access point, seems like you have conclusively demonstrated that your Ubuntu system is properly configured and not a likely culprit. Time to take another look at your router, especially the IP address range that it issues and the DNS servers that it knows about.

Comment: try `cat /etc/resolv.conf` and `ls -l /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: @StephenBoston  Results from your suggestion are posted in OP under UPDATES.  Looking forward to your interpretation of the results

Comment: Okay. For a try: delete the link to resolv.conf and recreate it using two lines: `nameserver 1.1.1.1` and `nameserver 1.0.0.1`. If your name lookups then work we know something new. You can easily recreate the link so that's okay.